# С помощью какого элемента решить задачу?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть задача - вывести набор кусков текста.
Требования к выводимому элементу:
- элемент должен обрабатывать нажатие на него
- элемент должен поддерживать форматирование текста
- в элемент можно вписать произвольное кол-во текста

Что пробовал:
- listview, datagrid
Не понял, как побороть форматирование текста и проблему переноса слов
Возможно (и скорее всего) я был не прав.
Или есть ещё варианты решения?
Спасибо!

**UPD**
Пол форматированием текста я понимаю вывести различные элементы текста различным начертанием. Например - кусок текста выделен жирным

Comment: ```RichText```?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, Datagrid позволяет редактировать текст

Comment: @Qwertiy richtext не подходит - нет возможности вывести набор нажимающихся абзацев. Или есть?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko в DataGrid можно вставить набор текста с различным начертанием?

Comment: @AntonZhitarev, можно вывести несколько RichText'ов считая каждый за отдельный элемент и объединить их в каком-нибудь StackPanel.

Comment: @AlexKrass, кстати, интересный вариант! Спасибо, попробую.